# Compute standar deviation in Pandas.DataFrame with custom mean value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I am facing the following problem:
I would like to be able to obtain the standard deviation for a group of values. The difficulty is in obtaining the std by applying the usual equation, but replacing the sample mean by a dataset mean.

To clarify where the problem comes from, this is an example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'X': ['asdf'] * 15,
    'Y': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'A': [58781, 60775, 61424, 61620, 60882, 58788, 57939, 60212, 59086, 59119, 59119, 59119, 59119, 59119, 59119],
    'B': [1.2, 1.6, 1.7, 2.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.2, 1.9, 2.3, 2.2, 2.2, 2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5],
    'C': [4.4, 4.2, 5.8, 4, 4.3, 4.5, 4.3, 5.2, 5, 3.8, 4.1, 4.5, 4.4, 4.5, 4.3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The standard deviation I want to obtain is for the values grouped by characteristic 'X' and 'Y' (there are more values of 'X' that I have not added in the example), but the mean I want to apply in the equation is the one corresponding to the whole group 'X'.

This has led me to develop the following code:

```
def custom_std(df, means, features, axis=0, ddof=0):
    x = df['X'].iloc[0]
    x_means = pd.concat([means[means['X'] == x][f]] * len(df[features]), ignore_index=True)
    sum_diff_sqr = np.sum(np.square(df[features] - x_means), axis=axis)
    variance = sum_diff_sqr/(len(df[features]) - ddof)
    std_dev = np.sqrt(variance)
    return std_dev

df_means = df.groupby(['X'])['A', 'B', 'C'].mean(numeric_only=True).reset_index()
df_custom_std = df.groupby(['X', 'Y']).apply(custom_std, df_means, ['A', 'B', 'C']).reset_index()
```

The only thing I have managed to get after several tests is a null std. I have come to verify that the subtraction `df[features] - x_means` results in invalid values (NaN). What I hope to get is a standard deviation which I don't see being possible unless I implement this method of my own.
The expected output should look like this (values do not correspond but this is the idea):

```
X       Y       A           B         C                                      
asdf    1       372.856882  0.408455  0.038759
        2       369.726386  0.307087  0.005963
        3       221.698686  0.038759  0.172923
qwer    1      1811.662275  0.028749  0.009583
        2      1811.662275  0.373743  0.456797
        3      1019.000000  0.167857  0.910714
zxcv    1       430.577250  0.268328  0.199755
        2       714.110669  0.044721  0.426344
        3       931.635362  0.313050  0.336901
uiop    1       916.638800  0.026833  0.921260
        2       559.762350  0.107331  0.831817
        3       640.558940  0.062610  0.509823
lkjh    1       782.975174  0.041527  0.779429
        2       104.104936  0.003194  0.651654
        3       378.107143  0.046429  0.328571
mnbv    1       223.964569  0.512805  0.432306
        2        88.011636  0.602248  0.655913
        3       398.556756  0.333919  0.432306
fghj    1       465.549353  0.140553  0.527073
        2       898.500000  0.192857  0.289286
        3       338.093478  0.185274  0.214024
```

Moreover, I have doubts whether the correct method is `apply` or `transform`.
Can someone help me? Please. I have researched for any work already done but I could not fine something matching the criteria.

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: There you go in the edit, thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to verify since you did not provide a calculated example, but the answer below takes advantage of index alignment between data frames:

```py
features = ["A", "B", "C"]
ddof = 1

# For each group, calculate the difference between each value and the custom mean.
# The two data frames are aligned on X since it's common in both indices.
diff = df.set_index(["X", "Y"])[features] - df.groupby("X")[features].mean()

# Variance
group = diff.pow(2).groupby(["X", "Y"])
variance = group.sum() / (group.count() - ddof)

# Standard Deviation
std = variance ** 0.5
```